# Does MonkeyTalk support localization in Android?

Tags: android, button, localization, record, monkeyrunner

When I record an action (for eg: button click) MonkeyTalk records the button text as a String so it doesnt work when I change the language on the device to non-English.

Eg: Button nein tap 
works fine in German language but doesn't work when I change the language to English.

Just want to know if there is any support in Monkey Talk to support localization or if there are any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by getting all the fields for Android Resources

```
    Map<Integer, String> idMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    Class<?> r;
    String rClass = "android.R$id";
    try {
        r = Class.forName(rClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.log("Unable to load " + rClass + ": " + e1.getMessage());
        return idMap;
    }
    for (Field f : r.getFields()) {
        int val;
        try {
            val = f.getInt(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get value for " + f.getName() + ": "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        idMap.put(val, f.getName());

    }
```